# How to apply the Realm token in React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

We are developing a react native app and the db that we used is realm. My development environment in Linux(Ubuntu specifically). We tried to implement the token (a free trial token) for us to sync the data coming from the app to the object server.

Problem is, we have encountered an error. This is the error:

Undefined is not an object Realm.Sync.setFeatureToken(token)

Can someone here help us with this issue that were encountering?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: yep having the same issue, realm documentation is poor so is not helping